# Does the iOS app icon have the red notification indicator?

Tags: support, ios-app

Would it be a nice idea to have the iOS app icon show the red notification circle when reputation changes, or comments are left?

It would save time, from having to open up the app, just to find that no reputation changes, have occurred, and no comments have been left.

The number would obviously reflect the number of comments, and/or reputation changes.

To clarify, this is what I mean:

[image: iOS app icon red number example]

This must be a duplicate question, but I can't find any sign of anyone having asked it.

#### Edit

The reason that no one posted this question is because everyone else probably has their settings correctly set in the Notifications section of the Settings app... I had mine turned off!

Comment: We already surface unread comments (anything that's an inbox notification, really) as a badge icon. Achievements are harder - what would the number be? IIRC you can only have one counter, so you'd have to choose between either rep or unread messages. We don't (currently) have a way to just say there are 5 new rep changes, for example.

Comment: @AdamLear - `We already surface unread comments as a badge icon` - I'm not sure what you mean by "badge icon". Do you mean that the red notification circle should be appearing already? I never seem to see it. I am running iOS 7.1.2, and have not upgraded for sometime (and I'm not about to). However, could that be part of the problem? However, I do agree that numerating rep changes could be problematic.

Comment: Yeah, if you're getting push notifications in the app (you might need to enable that if it's not already enabled), you should already be seeing the unread count as a red icon. OS/app version shouldn't matter (pretty sure we never shipped one without notifications).

Comment: @AdamLear - D'oh! I have just enabled `Badge App Icon` in the Settings app for the Stack Exchange app. I shall let you know if I see any subsequent "red notification circles". Methinks, I'll need to delete this question for the reason of "Don't know how to use my own phone"! Let's see... (How embarrassing)

Comment: Sounds good, let me know how it goes. :)

Comment: @AdamLear - yes, it works perfectly now. Red notification circles and messages on the lock screen too. Cheers. :-)

Comment: Don't delete, post a self answer explaining what you did, so others who fall into this will know how to "solve" it. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard ok, will do, when I get home.

Comment: @AdamLear So... is there a status message for this? It's not really "bydesign"... Maybe the title could be changed to "does" instead of "could"... or make it a FAQ and title it "how to turn on iOS app notifications for the SE app"?

Comment: @Catija - title changed to reflect user error :-)

Comment: @Catija Eh? I retagged to [support], not status tag needed. The rest is semantics and overthinking a little - we don't need an FAQ for using iOS, but it can't hurt to keep the question around overall. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To turn on, or check, that your notifications are correctly set, follow these steps:

1. Open the Settings app

> [image: Settings app on iOS]

2. Click on the *Notification Center* menu

> [image: Notification Center menu item]

3. Scroll down to find the Stack Exchange item

> [image: Stack Exchange app in the Notification Center]

4. Ensure that your settings are as follows

> [image: Correct settings for Notifications]